# Write NFC tag (using NTAG215)

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm currently working with android app that uses NFC technology. I'm new to this so a help would be appreciated. I am currently using NTAG215. Here's my main activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
NfcAdapter adapter;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
boolean writeMode;
Tag myTag;
Context ctx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ctx=this;
    Button btnWrite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);

    btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(myTag==null){
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_detected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }else{
                    write(name.getText().toString(),myTag);
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.ok_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_writing) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };

}



private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    ndef.connect();
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    ndef.close();
}



private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang       = "en";
    byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength = langBytes.length;
    int    textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.ok_detection) + myTag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    WriteModeOff();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    WriteModeOn();
}

private void WriteModeOn(){
    writeMode = true;
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
}

private void WriteModeOff(){
    writeMode = false;
    adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
```

}
When I run it, after I input text and click the button "Write" the app display this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWIDx.jpg) If the writing was error atleast it will have display a error text that I made right? so Idk what is this anymore.
I try to read some of the work and asked question here but some of the is either not answered or not updated. and most of them are written on kotlin which I do not know a lot. I also heard
`enableforgrondDispatch` i can use  `enableReaderMode` dont know if that is correct.
Idk if the code was never a working one or if my tag tech has different format
if you have a code suggestion you can leave it. also if you happen to know these tag technology that will suffice this project, let me know.
**If you know what was going on here, please let me know. thanks**
please help me with this one guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you are seeing is that most Tags don't come setup for storing ``Ndef` data on them, you need to format them first.

There is a lot of other problems with the code but when you `get` a Tag you should check the return is not `Null` which indicates that the Tag is not the type your are trying to get.

In your case code like should fix this problem:-

```java
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
if (ndef != null) {
    // It's a Ndef formatted Tag
    ndef.connect();
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    ndef.close();
} else {
    NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
    if (ndefFormatable != null) {
        // Format tag and write message
        ndefFormatable.connect();
        ndefFormatable.format(message);
        ndefFormatable.close();
    } else {
        // Throw an error message
        // Saying wrong type of Tag
    }
}
```